# Refactoring LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0

Consider the below

```
if(type== "S")
{   
    lstItem.ItemsSource = (from item in Items
              where item.Property1 == "SomeValue"
              select item);
}
else
{
    lstItem.ItemsSource = (from item in Items
              where item.Property2 == "SomeOtherValue"
              select item);
}
```

As can be figured out that the only difference between these two queries is only in the property name (for the first one it is **Property1** &  for the second it is **Property2**)

Is there any better way of refactoring / writing the code in a structured mannner(some common method where only the property name will be passed and the record will be filtered as per that)  or this is the proper way of doing the same?

Need help.

Thanks

Comment: You could do it with a generic method and use reflection over an 'Item' in 'Items' if they all implemented a common interface with property names on, but seems a bit overkill for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is also possible to add an inline if in the where clause

```
lstItem.ItemsSource = 
     (from item in Items
      where (test == "S" ? item.Property1 == "SomeValue" : item.Property2 == "SomeOtherValue")
      select item);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chain your commands within if statements.  E.g.:

```
var items = from item in Items 
            select item; 

if(type== "S")  
{     
   items = items.Where(item => item.Property1 == "SomeValue");
}  
else  
{  
   items = items.Where(item => item.Property2 == "SomeOtherValue");
}
```

Or even just write the tidier lambda structure in you orignal code:

```
if(type== "S") 
{    
    lstItem.ItemsSource = Items.Where(item => item.Property1 == "SomeValue");
} 
else 
{ 
    lstItem.ItemsSource = Items.Where(item.Property2 == "SomeOtherValue");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `items` at all? Why not perform `.Where(...)` directly on `Items`?

Comment: @stakx - already thought of that - check the edit.  The first would be good if there was a common filter.

Answer (score 3):

I like:

```
lstItem.ItemsSource = Items.Where(type == "S" ? 
                 item => item.Property1 == "SomeValue":
                 item => item.Property2 == "SomeOtherValue");
```

Comment: Oops, Wouter was the first one)

Answer (score 2):

well, you could start by boiling the expression down to:

```
Func<Items, bool> expr;

if(type== "S")  
{ 
    expr = (item => item.Property1 == "SomeValue");
}
else
{
    expr = (item => item.Property2 == "SomeOtherValue");
}

var items = Items.Where(expr);
```

of course, the game plan is really to make it all a single statemnet, but this makes it a LITTLE more manageable i think :)

jim